# Why doesn't C code return a struct?

Tags: c, return

While it's very handy, I very rarely, if ever, come across functions that return `struct`s (or `union`s) in C, whether they are dynamically linked functions or statically defined functions.
They instead return the data through a pointer parameter.

(An dynamic example in Windows is [`GetSystemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724381.aspx).)

What's the reason behind this?
Is it because of a performance issue, an ABI compatibility issue, or something else?

Comment: Please clarify, are you *only* asking why functions usually do not return a struct (or are you asking why programmers choose to not return a pointer to a struct, but rather use a parameter with a struct pointer, as well).

Comment: One context where I've seen it used (and used it) extensively was when we had a proprietary system with its own programming language that supported multiple return values for functions, for example instead of `ptr_buf = malloc(size_t_required)` it had `allocate(int_size_required:ptr_buf,int_size_actually_allocated)`. The system APIs also had C bindings, and the C bindings for functions that returned multiple values always returned structs. This caused no particular problem other than that it's quite tedious to define (and name) a different struct for each function if you're doing it manually.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I would say "performance", plus the fact that it's even possible sometimes seems to surprise C programmers. It's not ... in the general "flavor" of C, to many, to throw around large things such as structs as if they were mere values. Which, according to the language, they really are.

Along the same lines, many C programmers seem to automatically resort to `memcpy()` when the need to copy structs arises, rather than just using assignment, too.

In C++ at least, there is something called "return value optimization" which is able to silently transform code like this:

```
struct Point { int x, y; };

struct Point point_new(int x, int y)
{
  struct Point p;
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  return p;
}
```

into:

```
void point_new(struct Point *return_value, int x, int y)
{
  struct Point p;
  p.x = x;
  p.y = y;
  *return_value = p;
}
```

which does away with the (potentially stack-hungry) "true" return of a struct value. I guess even better would be this, not sure if they're that smart:

```
void point_new(struct Point *return_value, int x, int y)
{
  return_value->x = x;
  return_value->y = y;
}
```

I'm not sure if C compilers can do any of this, if they can't then I guess that might be a real argument against struct returns, for very performance-critical programs.

Comment: And yes, I realize the sample code is not picture-perfect C++, I wanted to write it as C in order to illustrate things better in the context of a C question.

Comment: I had this memory that the calling conventions for functions already require the caller to allocate space for the object if a function returned a struct to the stack, which the callee would then fill in.  Normally the return value goes in a register but in this it wouldn't fit.  Other approaches would require the return value and parameters on the stack to overlap, potentially, which is more complicated.

Answer (score 8):

The reasons are mostly historical. In his paper, ["The Text Editor `sam`"](https://web.archive.org/web/20040311190723/http://cm.bell-labs.com:80/sys/doc/sam/sam.html), Rob Pike writes

> A related matter of programming style: `sam` frequently passes structures by value, which simplifies the code. Traditionally, C programs have passed structures by reference, but implicit allocation on the stack is easier to use. Structure passing is a relatively new feature of C (it is not in the standard reference manual for C<sup>14</sup>), and is poorly supported in most commercial C compilers. It’s convenient and expressive, though, and simplifies memory management by avoiding the allocator altogether and eliminating pointer aliases.

That being said, there are pitfalls to the technique; returning obscenely large structures chances stack overflow.

Answer (score 7):

Returns in C are made by storing the return value in the [stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack). 
Returning a struct or an union would lead to put potentially very big data on the stack, and this could lead to a [stack overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_overflow).

Returning only a pointer to the struct/union is pretty much safier because you only put a little quantity of data (4 bytes in general) in the stack.

Comment: And also this makes it necessary to redundant copying of the entire returning data.

Comment: I don't think this can possibly be the whole reason. Creating very big data on the stack by any means risks stack overflow, but C programmers seem to avoid structs *as return values* in situations where they wouldn't avoid creating the same struct as a local variable. For example, with `struct tm` you often put one on the stack and pass a pointer to it into `localtime_r`. Programmers wouldn't do this if they were genuinely scared of a stack overflow. I suppose it might be that the `localtime_r` interface is cleverly designed to support platforms where 9 words is a lot and you'd malloc.

Comment: ... but I don't think that's very plausible. It probably has more to do with perceived performance: cleverly supporting platforms whose ABI and/or optimizer can't do RVO and where unnecessary copies are worth avoiding.

Comment: I'm not going to downvote you, but this is far from correct.  Plenty of architectures & ABIs strive to use registers for return values whenever possible.  For example, on ARM, returning a 32-bit int would return the value in register R0.

Comment: Not a satisfactory answer. Assuming the structure is returned on the stack, it would require the same stack size or more to declare the structure (as a local variable), then pass it as a pointer. It probably has to do with temporaries (i.e. lack of RVO in old compilers), but that should have been explained.

Answer (score 6):

A C function can return a structure (and so does a C++ one, where it is quite common). Perhaps in the very first years of C, it could not.

The [x86-64 ABI specification](http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) for Linux and related systems (page 21) even says that structures fitting into two -64 bits- words can often be returned in two registers without going thru the memory (even the stack). Very probably this is faster than going thru the stack.

As *unwind* replied in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8728849/841108), the ABI often requires structure results to be silently converted to an invisible pointer.

One could even define another calling convention which returns more data in more registers. But such new conventions would break all object code and require recompilation of everything (including even, on Linux, system libraries like `libc.so.6`), and of course require changing the compiler.

Of course, ABI conventions are processor, system and compiler related.

I don't know Windows and I don't know what Windows define as its ABI.

Comment: I think the 32bit ABI (maybe 64bit) makes it somewhat problematic, because the caller is responsible for popping the struct from the stack. So if the caller has no declaration (too common in C), and he just ignores the returned struct, the stack gets corrupt. This would be really hard to debug.

Answer (score 4):

In pre-ANSI C, you couldn't return object of structure type and you could also not pass arguments of structure types.

From Chris Torek quote in comp.lang.c:

> Note that V6 C also did not support struct-valued arguments and
>   struct-valued return values.

The reason nowadays they are not very used is people prefer to return pointer to structure which involves only a pointer copy instead of the copy of a whole structure object.

Comment: Just a note to be clear for any readers: the Chris Torek quote is from 1998 and refers to the 16-bit MS C Version 6 (from 1989), not Visual C++ 6 (from 1998) which has no problem passing or returning structs by value when compiling C code (or C++ for that matter).

Comment: @MichaelBurr I don't think it refers to MS C 6. The struct-valued arguments and return value do work in MS C 5.1 (which can be downloaded from winworldpc).

Comment: @raymai97 correct, V6 refers to [Version 6 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_6_Unix)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the idea that there might be a performance hit or that returning structs by value might not have been commonly supported in pre-standard days another reason for C functions to not use return-by-value for structs is that if you return a struct you can't easily return a success/failure indicator.  I know that I occasionally would start out designing a function to return a struct that was initialized in the function, but then I'd run into the problem of how to indicate whether or not the function succeeded.  You pretty much have the following options:

- guarantee success (sometimes this is possible)
- pass in a pointer to a location for the error code
- have a field or sentinel value in the struct that indicates success/failure

Only option 1 keeps the interface from being a kludge.  The second option kind of defeats the purpose of returning the struct by value, and actually makes the function more difficult to use for handling failures.  The third option is just plainly not a good design in nearly all cases.

Answer (score 0):

In general, Windows functions either return nothing or error codes, especially when it comes to returning structures or classes.

Efficiency might be an issue, although RVO **should** remove the overhead.

I think the main reason was to keep the methods inline with the coding style used before.