# How to return a struct from a class in C++?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a problem in returning a struct from a method declared in a class. The struct *i* is composed by 3 integers: *day*, *month* and *year*.
I set these three values using a method in the class.

```
struct dmy{
   int day, month, year;
};
dmy c;
```

Then I have a method to return the full struct

```
dmy Date::getS(){
  return c;
}
```

But I get lots of errors in compiling. What should I do?

I've also read [Is it safe to return a struct in C or C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590827/is-it-safe-to-return-a-struct-in-c-c) but I haven't solved my issue.

The program is composed from `main.cpp`, `Difference.h` and `Date.h`

Errors in Date.h :

`[Error] 'dmy' does not name a type`

**Main**

```
using namespace std;

#include <iostream>
#include "Date.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    Date date1;
    Date date2;

    cout<<"Insert first date\n";
    date1.setAll();

    return 0;
}
```

**Date.h**

```
class Date{
public:
    Date(){
    }
    ~Date(){
    }
    void setAll();
    struct dmy{
        int day, month, year;
    };
    dmy c;
    dmy getS();
private:
    void setDay();
    void setMonth();
    void setYear();
};

void Date::setAll(){
    setDay();
    setMonth();
    setYear();
}

void Date::setDay(){
    do{
        cout<<"Type day: ";
        cin>>c.day;
    }while(0<c.day<31);
}

void Date::setMonth(){
    //didn't right the checking again
    cout<<"Type month: ";
    cin>>c.month;
}

void Date::setYear(){
    cout<<"Type year: ";
    cin>>c.year;
}

dmy Date::getS(){
    return c;
}
```

***NOTE:*** The struct was called '*i*'

Comment: Show your errors. To an experienced eye, the error tells exactly what is wrong and how it might be fixed.

Comment: Show us the errors you get.

Comment: Ok, I am writing from my tablet unfortunatelly, so it's not so easy. At school we don't have internet access.

Comment: I am writing errors just a moment thank you

Comment: Do you declare `struct i` in a header file? Do you include that header file?

Comment: Yes, I included the header file in main, but not in Differece. Should I do so?

Comment: @AlessioMTX: You'll need to declare `struct i;` (or include the header if you need the full definition) in every file that uses it.

Comment: Also, you probably shouldn't name your struct *i*. *i* is often used as a variable name.

Comment: Did you try defining c as "struct i c;"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of

```
dmy Date::getS(){
    return c;
}
```

write

```
Date::dmy Date::getS(){
    return c;
}
```

since "dmy" is not in the global namespace.

Comment: That would be true if dmy was a nested class. But is not

Answer (score 2):

**Example**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>

struct DateInfo {
   int day;
   int month;
   int year;
};

class Date {
 public:
   Date(const int day, const int month, const int year) : m_info( { day, month, year } )
   {
      //n/a
   }

   DateInfo get_info( void ) const
   {
     return m_info;
   }

 private:
   DateInfo m_info;
};

int main( int, char** )
{
   Date date( 29, 02, 1984 );

   DateInfo info = date.get_info( );

   printf( "%i\n", info.year );

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Build**

> g++ -std=c++11 -o date date.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class C1
 {
public:
 struct S1
  {
  int a,b,c;
  };

 S1 f1() { S1 s; return s; }
 };

void main()
 {
 C1 c;
 C1::S1 s;

 s=c.f1();
 }
```

- C1 - class
- C1::S1 - struct inside class C1
- C1::f1 - function returning C1::S1

Comment: Embedding the structures definition within the class can cause problems with compile time dependencies.  If you alter the S1 structure all those including the C1 header will need to be recompiled.  Benefits can come from extracting the structure and forward declaring it when needed. see Compilation Firewall http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PimplIdiom

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your source code is compiled in the C style other that C++ style. You could try to change the file extension to ".cpp" instead of ".c" and then gcc will do it's job in C++ style.